# Configuring Blocks and the use of wild cards

Tags: blocks

Quite inexperienced in Drupal. 
I want to place a Block in my site, but I want it hidden on Front Page, on any node and on any user page (except */user/login* and */user/register* and */user/password*).
If I chose to “Hide for the listed pages”: 
*/node/*
/user/*
*
The pages: */user/login* and */user/register* and */user/password* will also be excluded

Is there a will card just for numbers? That would allow me to exclude the user profiles but not those 3 pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions based matching is not yet supported on D8 block visibility patterns and wildcards. The best bet at this point is the following module:
https://www.drupal.org/project/block_visibility_groups

You can add multiple rules to show or hide blocks.